# Jooq - interval 2 weeks

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

i need create interval in JOOQ, in SQL its look like that:

```
and dateFiled + interval '2 weeks' >= now()
```

i have tried:

```
DayToSecond dayToSecond = new DayToSecond(14, 0, 0, 0);
        .and(NOVELTY_FIELD.plus(dayToSecond).greaterOrEqual(Date.valueOf(now)))
```

```
Field<Date> dateField = DSL.dateAdd(NOVELTY_FIELD, 14, DatePart.DAY);
        .and(dateField.greaterOrEqual(Date.valueOf(now)))
```

Any ideas how i can do that in jooq?

Comment: Why didn't your attempts work?